# Tab Validation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

User

```dart
TextFormField(
                          enableInteractiveSelection: false,
                          controller: _runningKmsController,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          inputFormatters: [
                            LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(3)
                          ],
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            calculateTotalKms();
                            monthlyTotalCost();
                            monthlyTotalEvCost();
                            calculateTotalCostPerMonth();
                            calculateTotalCostPerMonthEv();
                            calculateMonthlySavings();
                          },
                          
                          cursorColor: AppTheme.appColors,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            // hintText: 'Enter your text here',
                            border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppTheme.appColors),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
TextFormField(
                    enableInteractiveSelection: false,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    cursorColor: AppTheme.appColors,
                    controller: _noOfWorkDaysController,
                    inputFormatters: [LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(2)],
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      calculateTotalKms();
                      monthlyTotalCost();
                      monthlyTotalEvCost();
                      calculateTotalCostPerMonth();
                      calculateTotalCostPerMonthEv();
                      calculateMonthlySavings();
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      // hintText: 'Enter your text here',
                      border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                        // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppTheme.appColors),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

I have 2 text form fields. Restrictions are required from 50 to 250 in the runningkmscontroller. A pop-up should be shown once the user shifts to the next tab. If the user enters a value less than or greater than the given range, validation should be performed. Additionally, onChange() function calculates different values. How can I achieve this? Please provide a solution.